# How to edit this table data to become a link

Tags: php, woocommerce

i am using a table on my website for products. 
At the moment only the image is clickable but i want the whole line or at least all the information in the table to be linking to the productpage.

The image has this and works as a link to the productpage:

```
<td style="width: 15%;">
    <div style="padding: 15px;">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank" class="thumbnail alignleft"><img src="<?php
            if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID))
            {
                $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'single-post-thumbnail');
                echo woof_aq_resize($img_src[0], get_tpl_option('tpl_3_img_width', $options), get_tpl_option('tpl_3_img_height', $options), true);
            } else
            {
                echo WOOF_LINK . 'img/not-found.jpg';
            }
            ?>" alt="<?php the_title() ?>" /></a>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</td>
```

Now i am trying to do the same thing for all the other info in the table wich have code like this:

```
<td style="width: auto;"><?php
    $product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID());
    echo $product->get_attribute('pa_voedings-spanning-dcac');
    ?>
</td>
```

Or even better make the whole line of the table a link. Thank you for your time,

Sjoerd

Comment: What is the problem? You seem to have found a solution. Regarding making a whole table row clickable, this is not possible. You'd need to either make the table out of single boxes (e.g. `<div>`s) or put an anchor into every cell.

Comment: Well at the moment only the image is clickable. I want the other information inside the table to also redirect to the product information as the image already does. Hope i made myself clear here.

Comment: You need to add the same anchor (`<a>`) you have around your image to every single table cell (`<td>`).

Comment: What he is saying is, you or someone else already managed to get the image to be clickable. All you need to do is apply the same system `<a></a>` to the rest of the elements. The link is created using the `the_permalink()` part. You could make the whole row clickable, but that would need the use of javascript.

Comment: Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 1):

You can simply wrapp each cell content with a "a" balise like this:

```
<td style="width: auto;">
    <?php $product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID()); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank">
      <?php echo $product->get_attribute('pa_voedings-spanning-dcac'); ?>
    </a>
</td>
```